# Is there a syntax completion mode or a way to do this in emacs?

Tags: emacs, syntax, autocomplete

In editplus we can define autocompletion keywords to insert pieces of code or blocks of code automatically. 
For eg. if I've defined something like below

```
    #T=ecp
    echo '<p>' . ^! . '</p>' . "\n";
    #
```

and now, whenever I type ecp I get the above code inserted automatically with cursor placed in the place of ^!.

I'm looking for a similar setting / function or a way to do the same.

Any ideas please ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emacs has [Abbrev Mode](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/AbbrevMode), it also has a variety of templating systems such as [yasnippets](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/Yasnippet).  One of these might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you. Both options were useful. But I'm settling with yasnippets.